# How to express inheritance hierarchies in TypeScript in a single file without ordering errors?

Tags: typescript

I'm generating TypeScript DTO classes from the backend Java model via a custom converter, and outputting it into a namespace based hierarchy into a single file.

When a class is extending another class that is defined later in the file (no matter if in same sub-namespace of different one), I get an error like **"class SliceDto used before its declaration"**.

Ordering the stuff isn't really an option since the classes might be in different packages, is there a clever way to get around this (they have to be classes, interfaces are not an option) ?

```
export namespace data {
    export class PageDto<T extends any> extends common.data.SliceDto<T> {
        public constructor(init?: Partial<PageDto<T>>) {
            super(init);
            Object.assign(this, init);
            // tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
            Reflect.defineMetadata('javaType', 'com.test.common.data.PageDto', this);
        }
        totalPages: number;

        totalElements: number;
    }

    /** Many more classes **/

    export class SliceDto<T extends any> extends Object {
        public constructor(init?: Partial<SliceDto<T>>) {
            super(init);
            Object.assign(this, init);
            // tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
            Reflect.defineMetadata('javaType', 'com.test.common.data.SliceDto', this);
        }
        content: T[];

        request: common.data.PageRequestDto;

        hasNext: boolean;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that Typescript still uses prototypical inheritance behind the scenes, so in order to inherit a class it's creation needs to have been executed:

So for example these classes:

```
class A {    
}

class B extends A {

}
```

Produce this code (when compiled to es5):

```
var A = /** @class */ (function () {
    function A() {
    }
    return A;
}());
var B = /** @class */ (function (_super) {
    __extends(B, _super);
    function B() {
        return _super !== null && _super.apply(this, arguments) || this;
    }
    return B;
}(A)); // A is needed here, if the creation of A has not been executed, we would have a problem.
```

The compiler does not allow you to this because it would cause runtime errors. You can get the compiler to stop complaining, if you use a self executing function, but **YOU WILL GET RUNTIME ERRORS AS A IS NOT INITALIZED YET**:

```
const B = (function () {
    return class B extends A {

    }
})();
type B = InstanceType<typeof B>;

class A {    
}

let b: B = new B();
```

Comment: If I modify the generator to put each class in a separate file and import the superclass, would the compiler be smart enough to arrange the order?

Comment: If you use a module system and import the base class it should work because then when you import the module the class definition will get executed and all will be right in the world :-)

Comment: Thanks, modifying the generator to output individual files and use the module system instead of the namespaces solved the issue.